# How to redirect URL with subfolder to the same URL but without subfolder?

Tags: redirect, urls, htaccess, domain

I have a WordPress site at `example.com/blog`. Now I want to remove the `/blog` subdirectory and just keep `example.com`.

However, other sites that are referencing my site still point to `example.com/blog`. How can I redirect all traffic including posts and pages going to `example.com/blog` to `example.com`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have already moved your site from the `/blog` subdirectory to the document root and changed the URL structure within WordPress itself, so the `/blog` subdirectory is not included in all your internal links, then you can either do a simple redirect (using mod_rewrite) in the `/blog/.htaccess` file (preferable):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [R=302,L]
```

This will redirect a URL of the form `/blog/foo` to `/foo`, since the captured backreference (`$1`) does not contain the directory-prefix when used in a *directory* context.

Alternatively, if you want to delete the `/blog` subdirectory altogether then you can do something like the following at the top of the root `.htaccess` file, *before* the WordPress front-controller:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*) /$1 [R=302,L]
```

Note that these are currently 302 temporary redirects. Only change to 301 permanent redirects when you are sure they are working OK.